# Does a Globe of Invulnerability spell block outsiders from teleporting inside with a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, teleportation

The [Globe of Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability) spell states:

> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can't affect creatures or objects within it, even if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot. Such a spell can target creatures and objects within the barrier, but the spell has no effect on them. Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.

The [Misty Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) spell states:

> you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

The [Dimension Door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) spell states:

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired.

Let's say that Bob casts Globe of Invulnerability; then Fred, who's outside Bob's globe, wants to teleport inside it (using Misty Step, or Dimension Door). Can Fred do that, or does the globe block outsiders from teleporting inside with a spell?

Answer (score 18):

### Both *Misty Step* and *Dimension Door* work unimpeded

*Misty Step* and *Dimension Door*, when cast on creature outside the barrier, do not affect or target creatures or objects within the barrier, and they don't affect an area. Furthermore, *Globe of Invulnerability* does not block vision (required for *Misty Step*), nor does it prevent targeting of points within it (required for *Dimension Door*). So it seems that **nothing in the text of *Globe of Invulnerability* would interfere with either of these spells.**

### Other teleportation spells might be affected

Note that while the two specific spells in the question are not blocked, not every teleportation spell is guaranteed to get through. For example, suppose you cast [*Steel Wind Strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/steel-wind-strike) targeting only creatures within the globe. The relevant parts of the spell's text are:

> [...] Make a melee spell attack against each target. [...] You can then teleport to an unoccupied space you can see within 5 feet of one of the targets you hit or missed.

If all targets are unaffected due to the protection of the globe, then you have not hit or missed any of them, because you have not attacked them. Therefore, you cannot teleport using the spell, since you have no valid targets to teleport next to.

So, it's important to read the text of the specific spell you want to use to determine what interaction it will have with *Globe of Invulnerability*.

Answer (score 8):

Since RAW, [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647), and Globe of Invulnerability does not specify protecting against teleportation or travel via the ethereal plane, it does not protect you against someone teleporting into the Globe.

Compare the description of the Globe to that of Forcecage, which specifically deals with this:

> If the creature tries to use teleportation or interplanar travel to leave the cage, it must first make a Charisma saving throw. On a success, the creature can use that magic to exit the cage. On a failure, the creature can't exit the cage and wastes the use of the spell or effect. The cage also extends into the Ethereal Plane, blocking ethereal travel.

As Globe of Invulnerability has no such provisions, it should not protect you against teleportation (although you cannot be pulled out from the outside.)

Answer (score 4):

> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can't affect creatures or objects within it, even if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot. Such a spell can target creatures and objects within the barrier, but the spell has no effect on them. Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.

There is an ambiguity here.

> Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.

What is "such spells"?

"such spells" could be "Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier", or it could be "Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier" that "target creatures or objects within the barrier".

I'd argue this is a weak ambuguity, because the previous sentence uses the same "Such a spell [...]" before it adds the "targets creatures [...] within".  The echo of "such" in two sentences means that the "such" relatively unambiguously referrs to the first sentence.

So, given "Any spell of 5th level or lower" that is "cast from outside the barrier", then:

1. It cannot affect creatures or objects within it.
2. Creatures or objects can be targeted within it, but it has no effect on them.
3. The area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affects by such spells.

And this holds even if cast using a higher level spell slot.

---

The next problem is Misty Step, and what "areas affected" means.

> you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

Is the unoccupied space you can see an "area affected" by Misty Step?  That could be interpreted either way.  Either no (because it is not part of the "area of effect" of Misty Step), or yes (because it is an identified area -- an unoccupied space -- and having someone appear in an area sure seems to affects it).

If yes, then Misty Step does not work through the barrier.  If no, then it works.

For Dimension Door:

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired.

There is less ambiguity here.  The "spot" doesn't read as explicitly as an "area" as an "unoccupied space" does.  You could stretch "area" to include the target location I suppose as well.  But it is more questionable.

---

In the end, Misty Step working is questionable, but Dimension Door almost certainly works.

To address other arguments:

1. A Darkness spell cast from outside wouldn't darken anything inside, because "Such spells" is clearly not limited to spells that "target creatures or objects".
2. The rules for Forcecage have nothing to do with the rules for Globe of Invulnerability, and it having special rules about teleportation doesn't change how Globe works.
3. Dimension Door targets a spot, while Misty Step targets an unoccupied space.  An unoccupied space is arguably an "area", but only arguably.  Given that the two spells are basically doing the same thing, and that DD works, and that area is *probably* intended to refer to spells that impose effects on measured volumes (like 20' spheres or the like), I'd make MS work myself.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first look at all of the relevant spell description of [*Globe of Invulnerability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability) (PHB 245):

> An immobile, faintly shimmering barrier springs into existence in a
>   10-foot radius around you and remains for the duration.
>
> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can't
>   affect creatures or objects within it, even if the spell is cast using
>   a higher level spell slot. Such a spell can target creatures and
>   objects within the barrier, but the spell has no effect on them.
>   Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas
>   affected by such spells.

Sadly Frederike "Fred" the Fighter is incapable of spellcasting so in this task she is replaced by Sabba "Sabba" the Sorcerer who can cast both [*Misty Step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) and [*Dimension Door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) and tries to reach Roberta "Bob" the Bard.

She first thinks that only creatures or objects within the globe are sheltered, so she ponders to cast [*Misty Step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) that targets herself, a creature, but she quickly revises her idea when she stumbles upon the thought that similarly the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells that target creatures or objects, so she will not be able to appear at the unoccupied space within the globe. She also won't be able to take Fred with her, who owes her a large sum of money.

Her rattling mind wanders and sets to attempt it with [*Dimension Door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) which she thinks will be successful because unlike [*Misty Step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) she targets a point of origin within the globe which is not such a spell that targets creatures or objects. She even gets to bring Frederike "Fred" the Fighter with her even though both are creatures.
As she casts [*Dimension Door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) her minds zeroes-in on the thought that the deciding factor is the targeting of the spell.

She will not only target the point of origin but also herself and Fred.

Targets (PHB 204):

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be
>   affected by the spell’s magic. A spell's description tells you whether
>   the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area
>   of effect (described below).

Well, at least that is what Sabba the Sorcerer thought until she realised that she and Fred safely arrived on the inside of the [*Globe of Invulnerability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability).

But how did this happen?

She tries her deductive reasoning of the Arcana (PHB 177) and recalls that both [*Misty Step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) and [*Dimension Door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) would have worked because her revised thoughts were based on an incorrect premise. Her incorrect premise was that "similarly the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells that target creatures or objects" when it should have been "similarly the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells that target creatures or objects within the barrier" which intuitively she knew through her innate skill granted to her by the raw power that chose her to be a sorcerer.

---

**Tl;dr: [*Globe of Invulnerability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability) neither blocks [*Misty Step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) nor [*Dimension Door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door)**

Comment: This would be a much better answer without all the in-character fluff.

Comment: @T.J.L. the answer is tailored to the question and has all information readily accessible and comprehensible contained within.
It is RAW and exhaustive. It works through the reasoning of the loop and addresses the issue.

If you want to downvote it because you prefer a reductionist answer go ahead. Do note that both of the other answers are incomplete compared to this one.

Comment: My objection is that this answer has twice as much text as it needs.

Comment: @T.J.L. that hardly sounds like an answer that would help Bob and Fred, but it easy enough to parse the relevant material for the ruling. To make it clear, I'm not going to cut out the humourous visual part of the answer.

Comment: If you, however, have trouble following the visual part and would like more clarification on anything I will gladly go into more detail or add another event if necessary. I'm open to (a constructive) critic that doesn't go against my intent of a visual answer.

Comment: The last paragraph (the one with the explanation of why it works) is awkwardly worded, which makes it much more difficult to understand than it needs to be. If you could re-word that paragraph to put the explanation in plain language this would be a much better language.

Comment: @Akixkisu - Definitely a personal preference thing but I've always preferred TL;DRs at the top and I think your answer would benefit from it as well. It gives me the answer immediately and then I have the option of reading the rational behind it, the TL;DR part prepares me for the fact that I'm about to see a wordy explanation so it comes as less of a shock to the system. As a reader on here I appreciate getting the answer quickly, but I also enjoy reading stylized answers (when time allows), with the TL;DR at the top I get both! Your choice of course, just trying to help constructively.

Comment: I think the "such spells" in the last sentence is intended to refer back to the "any spell of 5th level or lower" from the first sentence; it has nothing to do with spells that target a creature or object at all. It's meant to cover how area-of-effect, rather than specific target, spells interact with the globe.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist those spells are also of 5th level, but the conditional clause encompasses more than that.  The sentence is "Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can't affect creatures or objects within it" This is modified by that such spells can be targeted, but will not affect creatures or objects within the barrier. The last sentence is the tricky modified condition because it makes the case for e.g. a fireball that has a radius that includes the globe's radius but targets a creature just outside the globe.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I will think about adding the Tl;dr as the header and writing a plain text section at the end.

Comment: Since you asked for constructive criticism: The first narrative paragraph features a character reaching a *wrong* conclusion about how spells work.  Without a TL:DR at the *top* so readers already know where this is eventually going, it's easy to get lost.  It also makes this answer the opposite of skimmable.  If you want to explain why that reasoning doesn't apply, I'd recommend a section with a title about that.  hrule with `---` and sub-headings with `### Heading` can work wonders for breaking up an answer into separate parts about separate subjects.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, Globe of Invulnerability blocks teleportation from outside the barrier

---

### Globe of Invulerability Excludes Areas

Globe of Invulnerability states:

> Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas
> affected by such spells.

"such spells" refers to:

> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier

as opposed to spells cast from inside the barrier.

Since areas inside the Globe of Invulnerability are affected ***similarly*** to how creatures or objects are affected (by being excluded or unaffected), it follows that the areas affected by Misty Step and Dimension Door are ***similarly*** excluded by Globe of Invulnerability.

### Misty Step, Dimension Door, and Teleport Affect Areas

Misty Step states:

> you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

A space is an area.  See Player's Handbook p.191:

> A creature's space is the area in feet that it effectively controls in
> combat

Misty Step cannot affect a space within the Globe of Invulnerability.  You cannot Misty Step to inside it from outside of it.

Dimension Door states:

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot
> within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired. It can be a
> place you can see, one you can visualize, or one you can describe by
> stating distance and direction
>
> If you would arrive in a place already occupied by an object or a
> creature, you and any creature traveling with you each take 4d6 force
> damage, and the spell fails to teleport you.

A "place" can be "occupied by an object or creature", which means it is a space, which means it is an area.  Hence, Dimension Door cannot move you inside a Globe of Invulnerability from outside.

In the Teleport spell it states:

> to a destination you select.
>
> Familiarity. “Permanent circle” means a permanent teleportation circle
> whose sigil sequence you know. “Associated object” means that you
> possess an object taken from the desired destination within the last
> six months, such as a book from a wizard’s library, bed linen from a
> royal suite, or a chunk of marble from a lich’s secret tomb. “Very
> familiar” is a place you have been very often, a place you have
> carefully studied, or a place you can see when you cast the spell.
> “Seen casually” is someplace you have seen more than once but with
> which you aren’t very familiar. “Viewed once” is a place you have seen
> once, possibly using magic. “Description” is a place whose location
> and appearance you know through someone else’s description, perhaps
> from a map. "False destination” is a place that doesn’t exist. Perhaps
> you tried to scry an enemy’s sanctum but instead viewed an illusion,
> or you are attempting to teleport to a familiar location that no
> longer exists.
>
> Similar Area. You and your group (or the target object) wind up in a
> different area that’s visually or thematically similar to the target
> area.

A destination or place is an area because a "Similar Area" is a different "area".

It is possible that a Globe of Invulnerability does not cover the entirety of the destination.  There may be sufficient room outside the Globe of Invulnerabilty, but any space inside a Globe of Invulnerability (of sufficient level) cannot be affected by a Teleport from outside of it.

### Conclusion

Spells cannot teleport creatures or objects to inside a Globe of Invulerability from outside of it.

Comment: The first half sounds quite convincing (for misty step). I'm not sure on the place = area part, is the teleport section intending to demonstrate they are the same? If so, at least for me that is not easy to follow in the current version.

Comment: The text for Dimension Door demonstrates that a "place" can be "occupied by an object or a creature".
The text for Teleport refers to the destinations or places as areas by indicating that you can end up in a "different area".
I edited for additional clarity.